# Attribute selectors, JavaScript and IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, attributes

I'm attempting to use attribute selectors and CSS for formatting elements.

The HTML looks like:

```
<div id="user" highlight="false">User Name</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
[highlight=true]
{
    background-color: red;
}

[highlight=false]
{
    background-color: white;
}
```

And then there's some accompanying JavaScript:

```
if( foo )
{
    node.setAttribute('highlight', true);
}
else
{
    node.setAttribute('highlight', false);
}
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome. When the highlight attribute gets changed by the JavaScript, the element's background color changes as appropriate. In IE8, however, it's a different story. The element will display correctly according to the highlight value that is initially assigned in the HTML, but when the attribute is changed dynamically the display of the element doesn't change.

Is this a known quirk, and is there a known work-around?

**Update**
I just changed the attribute name to "frob" with values "on" and "off." That should settle any issue about reserved or interpretable values.

One other thing of note. When I turn on the IE8 developer tools and use the HTML inspector, it will show the style [frob=on] or [frob=off] as applied for whatever value frob had when I started the document inspector. However, the frob attribute will then no longer change in the inspector view. In no case do the values in the [frob=on/off] css ever get applied after the initial render of the HTML.

**Update: Problem Solved**
The solution is to force a redraw. There are various ways of doing this, but it appears the standard one is to reassign the className to itself.

Answer (score 2):

You're using unknown attribute `hightlight`. It's IE so it supports attributes according to its name (what's seems to be harder than supports every attribute name, but... it's IE).

Just use `class="hightlight"` - easier to implement and deal with.

Comment: I'm less than crazy about that approach because I already have applied a class to the div (not shown in the original code sample). Applying multiple classes to a node is a less than elegant solution. Of course, attribute selectors will be even less elegant if they require browser-specific workarounds.

Comment: Using a class attribute is the way to go even if there is more than one class applied. Maybe it's not elegant in your point of view but it's not exceptional. (Seperate 2 classes with one space)

Comment: I second using classes as well, as they will also work in browsers that don't support attribute selectors yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the attribute to JavaScript `true` and `false`, not string `"true"` and `"false"`. This *could* be interpreted by the browser as `1` and `0` and lead to unwanted results.

Can you try

```
node.setAttribute('highlight', 'true');
```

?

Comment: Changing the JavaScript to use the string forms doesn't do the trick. Thanks, though.

Comment: Ok. Can you still try something different than true or false, just to make sure no parsing kicks in? Does it work with a known valid attribute like `rel`?

Answer (score 0):

to avoid inevitable cross-browser compatibility issue's with javascript/css I would recommend using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

For example, to highlight an element via the jQuery framework this is all that it takes...

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have DOCTYPE defined at the top of the page: [Css attribute selector for input type="button" not working on IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185549/css-attribute-selector-for-input-typebutton-not-working-on-ie7/3386459#3386459)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I always have a DOCTYPE specified. My issue was not that IE wasn't evaluating the selector, it's that IE was not triggering to re-evaluate the CSS based on changes to the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have a DOCTYPE defined at the top of your page: [Css attribute selector for input type="button" not working on IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185549/css-attribute-selector-for-input-typebutton-not-working-on-ie7/3386459#3386459)