# Jeditable button styling problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, jeditable

I'm having problem with styling the submit and cancel buttons in IE8.
Using:

```
.editableTable button[type="submit"]
{
    background:url("../images/Ok-icon.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    border:none;
}
```

and

```
.editableTable button[type="cancel"],.editableTable button[type="button"]
{
    background:url("../images/Close-icon.png") no-repeat 0 0;    
    border:none;
}
```

I get what I want in FF and IE7 but in IE8 the button type is submit on both ok and cancel buttons so I get the OK-icon on both buttons. My other option was button:nth-child() but that doen't work in IE. So I'm stuck and really would appreciate any pointers...

Thank you!

Regards Sven

Comment: I read your question as "Jedi Table" :)

Comment: May the force be with you... :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a `Doctype` declaration. Try adding `<!doctype html>` at the top of the page before the `<html>` start and see what happens. Also there is a quirk where IE sometimes does not understand `type="submit"` but understands `type="Submit"` and vice versa. Try those as well.

Besides that a similar question has been asked a few times here on SO.

One of them is here 
[Css attribute selector for input type="button" not working on IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185549/css-attribute-selector-for-input-type-button-not-working-on-ie7)

--edit

Oh. Also found this question regarding selectors issue in IE8. [Attribute selectors, JavaScript and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112783/attribute-selectors-javascript-and-ie8)

Comment: I have this declaration in the Masterpage:  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: @Zwempha, Hmmm. Have you tried the answers in the other SO questions? Normally I try to stay away from the attribute seelctor in CSS because of this reason. If you can then I would highly recommend using classes and that works a whole lot better.